# Autolayout priorities for labels in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have designed custom cell as below.
[image]

It will show dynamic content. I am facing issue in assigning autolayout constraint priorities for top space , bottom space,vertical hugging priority,vertical resistance priority for these labels and set number of lines to zero and line break mode wordwrap.
I tried but some of the labels are getting cut as shown in following image:[image]

Any help in setting autolayout constraint priorities for labels will be appreciated..

Constraint for label1 is as shown in attached image[image]

Constraint for label2 is as shown in attached  image [image]

string=@"my Name is ........ my Name is ........ my Name is ";

In height for row:

```
static AttendeesListViewCell *sizingCell = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sizingCell = [self.attendeess_TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierAttendessWithImage];

});

sizingCell.attendessNameLabel.text = string;
        sizingCell.attendessTitleLabel.text = string;

 sizingCell.attendessCompanyLabel.text = string;
 sizingCell.label_city.text=string;
sizingCell.label_country.text=string;
```

[sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [sizingCell .contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

```
return size.height;
```

In cell for row:

AttendeesListViewCell *cell_attendee;
         cell_attendee = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierAttendessWithImage];
    cell_attendee.attendessNameLabel.text = string;
    cell_attendee.attendessTitleLabel.text = string;

```
cell_attendee.attendessCompanyLabel.text = string; 
cell_attendee.label_city.text=string;
cell_attendee.label_country.text=string;
 return cell_attendee;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Why it is not working...

Set number of lines for the label from code & xib file.

```
// Swift
textLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping // or NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0 

// Objective-C
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

set:
1. Base line as align base line,
2. Auto Shrink Fixed font size.

I can help on exact solution if you share the auto layout constraints that is applied to labels & code snippet.

Check if this is what you were expecting [link](https://github.com/sankarNarayanan/SampleAutoLayout)

Comment: Yes, I hv set  Base line as align base line and Auto Shrink Fixed font size.

Comment: I have attached image of label1 constraints.Top space and below space constraint priority is 1000.

Comment: Hey pls check this project.. See if this is what you were expecting..                 [link](https://github.com/sankarNarayanan/SampleAutoLayout)

Answer (score 0):

You may find you need to set the following property. I found I had to do this to get word wrapping to work correctly in multi-line UILabels in cells.

```
preferredMaxLayoutWidth
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth

You can set this on the constraint inspector window at the top for a UILabel.

Comment: I have set preferredMaxLayoutWidth property, but no luck.

Comment: Odd as it looks like your UILabel is wrapping the text but cannot show the whole string based on where it did the wrap so is truncating the middle. In iOS8 you want preferredMaxLayoutWidth set to auto. For iOS7 I think it has to be an explicit size. From your pictures I guess that needs to be around 220pts? I have also had issues with auto layout in tables and found doing an extra `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `viewDidAppear` solves some issues.

Comment: Just saw your update. In your height for row, you may also have to set the width of the cell as there are issues in iOS8 related to using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` for prototypes. The cell returned is not part of the table unlike that returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`. Check what the bounds width on the cell contentView is on the prototype cell returned. You will probably find its width is too wide which is throwing off your layout.

Comment: Thank you. One more issue I am facing is that suppose fourth label donot have text, then should I set top space and bottom space to zero for that particular label?

Comment: By default a UILabel will have a height of 1 line I think. I just tried the following and it seems to work. For each label add a constraint which sets the height to >=0. When there is no text this collapses to 0 height. When there is text it will grow to the height of the text. Give it a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Excellent. Can you update with the answer or select the answer you used please?

Comment: I had to set width for cell and for each label add a constraint which sets the height to >=0 and bottom constraint for imageview >=bottomSpaceValue.